# How to filter a LiveData in Android MVVM architecture after user input?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have a userlist of type LiveData that is shown in a recyclerview. Once I type something into an edittext, I simply want to filter the list.

I have seen in other examples that people are using Transformations.switchmap and calling something like userRepo.getFilteredList(searchQuery) in there. 
But since I have a very simple list and search I think it is better to apply the filter in in the viewmodel.

Is there a simple way like it.filter{item.name.contains(s)} to that livedata in the viewmodel? I am grateful for any kind of reference or tip.

Comment: no, you have to use `switchmap` - its really not so complex

Comment: I don't mind about using switchmap, I just don't want to fetch new data from the repository all the time. I just want to filter my full list that is already in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 3):

```
fun getFilteredList(s: String): LiveData<List<User>> {
    return Transformations.map(userListLiveData) {
        it.filter {
            it.name.contains(s)
        }
    }
}
```

I sorted it out :) There you go.